# How do I include the user objects n the json result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@song.likes.select('likes.*, users.*').includes(:user).to_json
```

Only converts the like objects. Is there a way to include the user objects in the json result? Via Ruby or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@song.likes.select('likes.*, users.*').includes(:user).to_json(:include => :user)
```

Would do what you want.

In Rails-JSON you have to explicitly specify which associations get traversed to prevent too deep object trees and circular references.